# Computing the entropy of a hidden word based on amount of information in each guess

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Say I'm playing hangman where I'm trying to guess a 7-letter word.
To guess the word, I pick one letter at a time, and if this letter appears in the word, it gets filled in.

[image]

Now let's assume the space from which words are chosen contains 12 7-letter words in a language whose alphabet only has 12 different letters.

I don't know the word that I'm guessing, but I do know how much information (in bits) I gain on average when I guess a letter in this word correctly. This information is summarized in the table below.

| letters guessed | E[I] | possible word matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.78 | 7.0 |
| 2 | 1.54 | 4.1 |
| 3 | 2.16 | 2.7 |
| 4 | 2.61 | 2.0 |
| 5 | 2.98 | 1.5 |
| 6 | 3.30 | 1.2 |
| 7 | 3.58 | 1.0 |

Is there anything I can learn about the amount of entropy this word has based on the data in the table above?

Edit:

This is how I'm computing E[I]
[image]

Comment: This question was just asked a few days ago (by someone else?). Where does it come from?

Comment: It was asked by me with confusing wording, so I deleted it and re-posted it with less clutter. It's not from anywhere. It relates to my work in music theory where I deal with 7-note scales and I'm developing a theory that incorporates information theory and music perception.

Comment: what is E[I]? How do you compute it?

Comment: I edited the question to include the formula for E[I]

Comment: As written, you are multiplying a number by its inverse, so the product is $1$.  You should also not be summing over $x$, but something like $i$ where the values are $x_i$

Comment: Oops, that was a typo! It's now corrected. I'm summing the self-information in bits contributed by each guess and weighting it by the likelihood of this guess to be correct.

Comment: surely you need $\sum_x p(x) \log_2(1/p(x))$

Comment: I don't believe so. The p(E) indicates by how much the space was narrowed. That is, given some letter, what proportion of words remain with the introduction of that letter. p(x) is the probability of guessing a particular letter. Assume I have scrabble tiles, and the tile I flip is the letter I guess. Then, if there is one scrabble tile for every letter, p(x) would equal p(E), but, I may have, say, more scrabble tiles with the letter "A" than tiles with the letter "X". So p(E) is the likelihood of a letter existing in the word and p(x) is the likelihood of picking a specific letter.